# How to Run HMS Apps Using Android Emulator?

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, huawei-mobile-services

Is there any way can we test HMS Apps in normal android emulators that are present in Android studio?

Answer (score 2):

How to Run **HMS Apps** Using **Android Emulator** :

Steps1: First you have to download HMS Core APK. Google it.

Steps2: Open the command prompt and install the HMS core Apk using **adb install location_of_hms_core.apk** command.

Steps 3: After installing the apk you will not be able to see the app. But you need to navigate to **settings** --> **all apps** --> **there you will find the app**.

Step 4: Provide all **permission** of the app right a way.

Step 5: Come back to your app and launch it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [HMS Toolkit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/huawei-toolkit/?ha_source=hms1) or [Cloud Debugging](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-clouddebug-realtimedebug?ha_source=hms1) to test your HMS app.

For Huawei emulator on Android Studio, you can install **HMS Toolkit**. As a lightweight IDE tool plugin, HMS Toolkit implements app creation, coding, conversion, debugging, test, and release. HMS Toolkit provides **Cloud Debugging** for you to perform 24/7 uninterrupted testing on your app running on remote real devices. With this function, you can learn about the running status of apps on Huawei devices anytime and anywhere even if no device is available, device types are not completed, or an error cannot be reproduced.

Cloud Debugging can be used on a single device for 2 hours each time. Before the validity period expires, you can release the device and apply for the device again.

Note: To use Cloud Debugging, you need to sign in using the Huawei Account, complete identity verification, and then authorize the sign-in. Internet Explorer and Chrome are supported. This function applies only to the Chinese mainland, Asia Pacific, and West Europe.

---

You can install HMS Toolkit in either of the following ways:

- Use the Android Studio Marketplace.
  Open Android Studio, go to **File** > **Settings** > **Plugins** > **Marketplace**, enter HMS Toolkit in the search box, and click Install. After the installation is complete, restart Android Studio.
- Import the local plug-in package. Download the HMS Toolkit package. Open Android Studio, go to **File** > **Settings** > **Plugins**, select Install Plugin from Disk, and finish subsequent steps. After the installation is complete, restart Android Studio.

Cloud Debugging:

A. Go to **HMS** > **Cloud Debugging** or click the icon shown in the following figure.

B. On the Select Remote Device page, you can select a required device by Resolution, Android Version, EMUI Version, Series, and Others. Alternatively, you can use Available Devices.

C. Click the selected device.

D. On the menu bar, click Debug to debug or run the app on the device. You can also run ADB commands to perform operations. For details, please refer to @[SanghatiM's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65885898/13329100).

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot test HMS Apps in a regular android emulators way. You will have to install HMS toolkit first and then use HMS Cloud Debugging and HMS Cloud Testing to test your HMS Apps.

1. HMS toolkit is a plugin installed in Android Studio to facilitate app creation (including development environment configuration), coding, conversion, debugging, test, and release to HUAWEI AppGallery Connect. More details at: [Here](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/Tools-Guides/overview-0000001050060881)
2. HMS Cloud Debugging:  debug your app using mainstream Huawei devices provided by Huawei in real time. More details at: [Here](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-clouddebug-realtimedebug)
   [image]
3. HMS Cloud Testing: You can also use HMS Cloud testing to carry out Compatibility Test, Stability Test and Performance Test and Power Consumption Test is needed. More info. at: [Here](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-cloudtest-introduction)
   [image]
4. One more step by step guidance of how to use HMS Toolkit and cloud debugging: [Link](https://medium.com/@tusharsri/debug-your-application-on-any-hms-supported-model-no-real-device-required-408a1e134782)